# Compute the Betti cohomology of the Blow up of $\Bbb{C}^2$ at $0$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I was trying to prove that for a complex surface $X$, if we blow up it at a point $p$ we have $$H^1(\text{Bl}_p X) \cong H^1(X), H^2(\text{Bl}_p X)  = H^2(X)\oplus \Bbb{Z}$$

In order to do this we use the Mayer- Vietoris sequence , therefore the problem reduce to compute the Betti cohomology of blow up of $\Bbb{C}^2$ at origin. which has explicit expression $$\text{Bl}_0\Bbb{C}^2 = \{ (x,\ell)\in \Bbb{C}^2 \times \Bbb{P}^1\mid x\in \ell \} $$

that is where I don't have idea how to compute, I try to use Mayer-Victories but it's not clear, do we need to use long exact sequence for relative homology to compute this, that is we need to compute the cohomology of the quotient space $\text{Bl}_0\Bbb{C}^2 / \Bbb{P}^1$, however, I can't see what is it?

Comment: The plane contracts to the origin? Can you do something similar with the blow-up?

Comment: Oh @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez , it contracts to $\Bbb{P}^1$!

Comment: If you've figured out an answer to your question then you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Ok  thank you @ronno , I will post an answer later